# No SSH link with Internet Explorer

Tags: github, firefox, internet-explorer

With Firefox

> You can clone with HTTPS, SSH, or Subversion

[image: firefox]

With Internet Explorer

> You can clone with HTTPS, or Subversion

[image: IE]

Why is Internet Explorer missing the SSH link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From: "John Greet (GitHub Staff)"
>
> Are you signed in to GitHub in Internet Explorer?
>
> SSH access requires a GitHub account with a public key associated with it, even
> for public repositories, so we don't show the SSH remote in any browser if you
> are logged out.